# $\alpha_1 \circ \alpha_2 = (1)$ Show that $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = (1)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove this:

Let $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ be two disjoint cycles in $S_n$ such that $\alpha_1 \circ \alpha_2 = (1)$ Show that $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = (1)$. Generalize this to the product $l$, $l \ge 2$, two-by-two separate round.

And I tried to prove it but I don't have the idea. However here's my way but my professor said it's not true:

If $\alpha_1 \circ \alpha_2 = (1)$, then for any element $x$ in the set $S_n$, we have $\alpha_1(\alpha_2(x)) = x$. This implies that $\alpha_2(x)$ is a fixed point of $\alpha_1$, and so $\alpha_1$ must be the identity permutation $(1)$. Similarly, $\alpha_2$ must also be the identity permutation.

To generalize this to the product of $l$ two-by-two separate rounds, suppose that $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_l$ are distinct circuits in $S_n$ such that $\alpha_1 \circ \alpha_2 \circ ... \circ \alpha_l = (1)$. Then for any element $x$ in the set $S_n$, we have $\alpha_1(\alpha_2(...(\alpha_l(x))...)) = x$. This implies that $\alpha_l(x)$ is a fixed point of $\alpha_{l-1}$, $\alpha_{l-2}(x)$ is a fixed point of $\alpha_{l-3}$ and so on. Thus $\alpha_l = \alpha_{l-1} = ... = \alpha_1 = (1)$.

Some other ideas I had was using the inverse and so on but didn't respond.

Comment: Do you mean *disjoint cycles* instead of *distinct circuits*?

Comment: @lhf yes. I'm sorry. I mean two Two separate cycles.

Comment: You claim that $\alpha_1$ must be the identity $(1)$ if it has a fixed point? No, certainly not. Take $\alpha_1=(23)$ in $S_3$. It fixes $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is wrong, perhaps because you misunderstood your teacher.

Given that $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are disjoint, each $x$ cannot be changed by both.
So, if $\alpha_1(\alpha_2(x))=x$, for all $x \in S_n$, then, for $x$ such that $\alpha_1(x)\neq x$, we have $\alpha_2(x)=x$, yielding
$$x=\alpha_1(\alpha_2(x))=\alpha_1(x),$$
a contradiction.

So $\alpha_1=(1)$ and that entails that $\alpha_2=(1)$.

---

For the general case, if $\alpha_1(\alpha_2(\cdots(\alpha_k(x))\cdots))=x$, apply the previous reasoning to $\alpha_1$ as before, and conclude that $\alpha_1$ must be the identity, and so $\alpha_2(\alpha_3(\cdots(\alpha_k(x))\cdots))=x$ (now, only $k-1$ cycles).
Proceed until there are only two, and conclude $\alpha_i=(1)$ for $1\leq i\leq k$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that $\alpha_2 \ne (1)$. Then $\exists x_0 \in S_n, \alpha_2(x_0) \ne x_0$. Let us call $x_1 = \alpha_2(x_0)$. Per $\alpha_1 \circ \alpha_2 = (1)$, we must have $\alpha_1(\alpha_2(x_0)) = x_0$ meaning $\alpha_1(x1) = x_0$.

So we have:

$$ 
\exists x_0, x_1 \in S_n, \left\lbrace
\begin{split}
x_0 \ne x_1 \\
\alpha_2(x_0) = x_1\\
\alpha_1(x_1) = x_0 
\end{split}
\right.
$$

This implies that $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ cannot be disjoint, which is a contradiction.

Hence $\alpha_2$ is $(1)$, and so is $\alpha_1$